# Create a Drive File with a set locale in international settings through Drive API

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, google-drive-shared-drive

I need to create a file using the Google Drive API (I'm using v3, the latest at the moment). Using python if it matters.

My code is below,

```
drive_service.files().create(supportsTeamDrives=True, body={
                    'name': 'test-file',
                    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
                    'parents': [folder_id],
                    'properties': {'locale': 'en_GB',
                                   'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin'}
                })
```

Following the documentation @[here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create), I tried to set the `properties` key with the locale set to the wanted one but it keeps creating the file with the default locale of my account.

How can I make it work at the creation time? is there another parameter I can fill?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the problem.  Can you show an example of what you think its wrong?

Comment: When it creates the file, the properties are not the ones I specified in the code, but the default ones

Comment: And your checking the newest file uploaded not one that you uploaded earlier?

Comment: Yes I did, there was no file uploaded earlier, only the one I'm creating

Comment: Yes but every time you run that its going to create a new file you understand.   I still dont understand where it is exactly that you say does not contain the data that you are looking for.  are you looking in drive? are you doing a file.get? are you just checking the response?

Comment: The file was being created, but as @pinoyyid suggested, the "properties" I wanted to set, that I checked by looking at the created file, were not those I was setting. As in your response, those properties were set but were not the ones I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are mixing up two different "properties".

The properties you are setting are user-defined properties which are only ever consumed by you yourself. They are of no significance to Google.

The properties you want to set are part of the Spreadsheet API. See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SpreadsheetProperties

The simplest solution is to not use the Drive API to create your spreadsheet. Instead use the Spreadsheet API as descibed https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create

Comment: This does work, I confused the two "properties" thinking they would have the same effect, however it seems the Spreadsheet API doesn't let you specify the folder in which to create the file, I solved it by creating it then moving it through Drive API

Comment: Alternatively, to fix a spreadsheet that already exists, one can issue a [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) request with `{"requests": [{"updateSpreadsheetProperties": {"properties": {"locale": locale}, "fields": "locale"}}]}` as its body.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this in the [Apis Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.create?_h=1&resource=%257B%250A++%2522properties%2522%253A+%250A++%257B%250A++++%2522test%2522%253A+%2522test%2522%250A++%257D%252C%250A++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522Hello%2522%250A%257D&)

**Create file Request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "properties": {
  "test": "test"
 },
 "name": "Hello"
}
```

Response

```
{    

 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1CYFI5rootSO5cndBD2gFb1n8SVvJ7_jo",
 "name": "Hello",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
}
```

**File get request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1CYFI5rootSO5cndBD2gFb1n8SVvJ7_jo?fields=*&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response

```
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1CYFI5rootSO5cndBD2gFb1n8SVvJ7_jo",
 "name": "Hello",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "parents": [
  "0AJpJkOVaKccEUk9PVA"
 ],
 "properties": {
  "test": "test"
 },
```

It appears to be working just fine i suggest you try checking the following:

- The file id that is returned in the response from creating the file. To ensure that you are checking the one you just uploaded.  Every time you run that you are going t create a new file.
- Also remember to add `fields=*` with `file.get` if that's what you are using to check the result of your properties.